# unable to add horizontal scrollbar to my chart

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on angularjs google charts. I am using angularjs google column chart to display the data in the form of columns, issue is when i have more data to show the bar width is reducing. I want to show the chart with horizontal scrollbar if the data is more to display as shown in the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGtvL/1/).
I tried to implement the same but unable to display the scrollbar,any suggestions would be helpful.

My sample demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sEszNxDtQDDOwaAUd5Sj?p=preview)

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
          f: "42 items"
        }, {
          v: 12,
          f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
          v: 7,
          f: "7 servers"
        }, {
          v: 4
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, {
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "April"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "May"
          }, {
            v: 18
          }, {
            v:11
          }, {
            v: 7
          }, {
            v:2
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "June"
          }, {
            v: 21
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 8
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "July"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 9
          }, {
            v: 9
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "August"
          }, {
            v: 14
          }, {
            v: 1
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 5
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "September"
          }, {
            v: 4
          }, {
            v: 2
          }, {
            v: 51
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "October"
          }, {
            v: 34
          }, {
            v: 4
          }, {
            v: 0
          }, {
            v: 1
          }

        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    chart1.view = {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;

    $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {
      console.log(selectedItem);
      var col = selectedItem.column;
      //If there's no row value, user clicked the legend.
      if (selectedItem.row === null) {
        //If true, the chart series is currently displayed normally.  Hide it.
        console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
        if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
          //Replace the integer value with this object initializer.
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = {
            //Take the label value and type from the existing column.
            label: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].label,
            type: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].type,
            //makes the new column a calculated column based on a function that returns null, 
            //effectively hiding the series.
            calc: function() {
              return null;
            }
          };
          //Change the series color to grey to indicate that it is hidden.
          //Uses color[col-1] instead of colors[col] because the domain column (in my case the date values)
          //does not need a color value.
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = '#CCCCCC';
        }
        //series is currently hidden, bring it back.
        else {
          console.log("Ran this.");
          //Simply reassigning the integer column index value removes the calculated column.
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
          console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
          //I had the original colors already backed up in another array.  If you want to do this in a more
          //dynamic way (say if the user could change colors for example), then you'd need to have them backed
          //up when you switch to grey.
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

I tried by adding the below code in my js code above in `chart1.options` but it didn't worked:

```
width: chart1.data.getNumberOfRows() * 130,
bar: {groupWidth: 90},
```

Comment: cant you use css for doing the same by setting the width ?

Comment: i have used but it is reducing the bar width when number of bars are more..I want to keep the same bar size as displayed now, so i think we need to handle it differently.

Comment: You want this ? https://plnkr.co/edit/GKhoyoC4zbrAzvfSa55U?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html you can set the width and set what to do on overflow like this

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div google-chart chart="myChart" style="width:400px;height:500px;overflow-x:scroll"></div>
    <br><br>
     <div google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
  </div>
```

or you can as well do

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
<div google-chart chart="myChart" style="height:500px;overflow-x:auto"></div>
<br><br>
 <div google-chart chart="myChart"></div>
```

In the fiddle you have attached,they have used css styling,Please reffer that.

**update**

and you have to set chart properties as

```
          "width": chart1.data.rows.length *65,
          "bar": {groupWidth: 20},
```

based on your requirement.The above configuration has to be manipulated according to your need.You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGtvL/1/) ie. the link you are reffering. Please find the plunk for the same https://plnkr.co/edit/o8iccmrB13NdDAKCxb7Z?p=preview (if you cant view it,please see in the version section)

**Update**
If you are using data from async call then ,set options inside

```
MyDataService.getChartDataFromService().then(
            function (response) {
//other codes
.......//set options here

}))
```

Comment: appreciate your help,things i noticed when used your code, even if the bars are few or none ,vertical and horizontal scrollbars are displayed. I dont want to show vertical scrollbar but with the property style="height:500px;overflow-x:auto" it is displaying vertical and horizontal scrollbar.can we disable vertical scrollbar and show the horizontal scrollbar dynamically only when the data is more to display?

Comment: overflow-x:auto" means scroll bar will appear only when the content is overflown.You can use overflow-y:hidden  to hide the vertical scrollbar

Comment: Please see my updated answer.you have to configure chart and make the bar width constant as well otherwise the chart will be responsive and auto change the width of the bars.Please see the fiddle you have attached for the example

Comment: hmm, that is where i'm failing to show as mentioned in my post above using the code you mentioned to add in chart properties. If you see my post above the same thing i mentioned. Can you please update the https://plnkr.co/edit/sEszNxDtQDDOwaAUd5Sj?p=preview with your updated code.

Comment: I recreated the plunk.Please find my updated answer.instead of width: chart1.data.getNumberOfRows() * 130,use width: chart1.data.rows.length* 130,it will do the trick..dont forget to specify,overflow-x:auto in the html

Comment: Plese see the edited section in my post. I'm generating the rows dynamically and that is where i could not able to get it work perfectly. If i give "width":30*65 instead of "width": $scope.chart.data.rows.length *130,
the tooltip is not showing properly.Any advice how to get the row count when rows are generated dynamically?@Vikhyath Maiya

Comment: that was not the original requirement !!

Comment: Appreciate your help. It is not giving the space between bars. I have kept alert statement for $scope.chart.data.rows and it is showing undefined. When i manually gave "width":10*70; it is giving space but tooltip is not showing for few bars when i mouse over for the last bars.

Comment: and please dont modify the questions like that ..your original question has been Answered properly and the edited question has to be asked as a new question as it is a whole different topic "how to handle asynchronous data in angularjs" ..

Comment: This is totally a different question related to tooltip and it has nothing to do with the original question. If the answer has solved your original question, please mark the ans correct and ask a new question ..

Answer (score 0):

In your div tag you need to set scroll for overflow.

```
<div google-chart chart="myChart" style="overflow:scroll"></div>
```

I make the changes in your demo.